# ¿Cómo puedo guardar múltiples archivos con un mismo ID?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Tengo un problema al intentar insertar los archivos en la base de datos. Me los ingresa de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que ingresen todos con el mismo `id`. Ejemplo:

```
id   file
15   bd1(Autoguardado).xlsx, Captura.JPG, combox filtro.JPG
```

Aquí está el código:

```js
//Iniciamos nuestra función jquery.
$(function(){
 $('#enviar').click(SubirFotos); 
});

function SubirFotos(){ 
  var archivos = document.getElementById("archivos");
  var archivo = archivos.files; 
  var archivos = new FormData();
  
  for(i=0; i<archivo.length; i++){
  archivos.append('archivo'+i,archivo[i]);  }

  /*Ejecutamos la función ajax de jQuery*/  
  $.ajax({
   url:'subir.php', 
   type:'POST', 
   contentType:false, 
   data:archivos, 
   processData:false, 
   cache:false 
  }).done(function(msg){
   MensajeFinal(msg)
  });
 }

function MensajeFinal(msg){
 $('.mensage').html(msg);
 $('.mensage').show('slow');//Mostramos el div.
}
```

**Subir.php**

```
<?php

require_once "conexion.php";
$conexion=conexion();
$ruta = './Files/'; 
$mensage = '';
foreach ($_FILES as $key) 
{
    if($key['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK )
        {
            $NombreOriginal = $key['name'];
            $temporal = $key['tmp_name']; 
            $Destino = $ruta.$NombreOriginal;       

            move_uploaded_file($temporal, $Destino);        
        }

    if ($key['error']=='') 
        {
            $mensage .= '-> Archivo <b>'.$NombreOriginal.'</b> Subido correctamente. <br>';
        }
    if ($key['error']!='')
        {
            $mensage .= '-> No se pudo subir el archivo <b>'.$NombreOriginal.'</b> debido al siguiente Error: \n'.$key['error']; 
        }
    $sql="INSERT into imagen (file) values('$NombreOriginal')";
    echo $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
}




echo $mensage;
?>
```

Comment: ¿En serio estás guardando archivos tal cual en la BD? ¿Por qué no lo gestionas en carpetas y en la BD solo guardas una referencia a: `nombre, carpeta, tipo`...?

Comment: Yo solo veo que guarda los nombres, pero la columna id no la especifica.  @claudia24 esa columna es AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: @alanfcm si, es auto_increment

Comment: @A.Cedano lo estoy guardando así, porque es un BD de prueba para ver si me resultaba, y luego aplicarlo de buena manera en otro lado

Comment: Claudia a tu pregunta le falta un detalle fundamental: ¿quieres que tengan el mismo id pero en filas distintas? En ese caso la columna id no puede ser autoincrement. ¿Quieres que estén en una sola fila? Entonces tendrías que concatenar los nombres de archivo con un separador dentro del bucle y hacer una sola inserción al salir del bucle.

Comment: @claudia24 Independientemente de todo lo comentado, **hacer lo que pretendes** es considerado una mala práctica y un error de diseño en cuanto que **no respeta ni 1FN**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la forma en la que tienes el diseño, es muy dificil hacer lo que pretendes.  Como la columna id es AUTO_INCREMENT, siempre te va a generar un id nuevo para cada INSERT.  La unica forma de hacerlo seria concatenando los nombres de los archivos separados por comas, pero como ya te explicaron, esto no es un buen diseño porque viola la primera forma normal.

Si la razon por la que quieres tener el mismo id es porque los archivos estan relacionados con alguna otra entidad, digamos un usuario, la forma correcta de hacerlo seria agregar una llave foranea que apunte a dicho usuario.  De esa forma, puedes relacionar los archivos que pertenezcan a un usuario con la misma llave foranea.

Comment: seguí tu consejo deje la foránea que apunta a otra tabla, disculpa la demora soy un poco olvidadiza.

Answer (score 1):

Te quería poner un comentario, pero me resulta difícil siendo que no se puede poner código. Solo tienes que declarar una variable fuera y antes del *for* en dónde ir guardando las imágenes y luego, al salir del *for*, realizar el *insert* una sola vez:

```
<?php
    require_once "conexion.php";
    $conexion = conexion();
    $ruta = './Files/';
    $mensage = '';
    $files = "";
    foreach ($_FILES as $key) {
        if($key['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {
            $NombreOriginal = $key['name'];
            $temporal = $key['tmp_name'];
            $Destino = $ruta.$NombreOriginal;
            move_uploaded_file($temporal, $Destino);
        }
        if ($key['error']=='') {
            $mensage .= '-> Archivo <b>'.$NombreOriginal.'</b> Subido correctamente. <br>';
        }
        if ($key['error']!='') {
            $mensage .= '-> No se pudo subir el archivo <b>'.$NombreOriginal.'</b> debido al siguiente Error: \n'.$key['error'];
        }
        $files .= $NombreOriginal . ", ";
    }
    $files = trim($files, ", "); // Quito la última ", " de la cadena
    $sql="INSERT into imagen (file) values('$files')";
    echo $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    echo $mensage;
?>
```